# Are the SSL private keys that are being distributed to the government agencies secure enough

Tags: .net, windows, iis, ssl

I have a question about the private keys that are shared with the CA authorities or government agencies. Are they secure enough to encrypt our data communication from windows application to the Remote Server or should we add another encryption layer above SSL?

Comment: If you're worried about government agencies seeing the data you're encrypting then I'd guess you're probably doing something you shouldn't be.

Comment: @M.Babcock Not true. I don't want government agencies to know my credit card number when I'm ordering on Amazon, because then someone there could charge my account. Desiring privacy does not mean illegal activities. Do you live in a glass house? Do you broadcast your entire showers to the Internet?

Comment: @McKay - If they wanted your credit card number they wouldn't need to monitor your network traffic to get it.

Comment: @M.Babcock But they'd have to violate the law, and either order Amazon to violate contracts, or talk to my bank or credit card company, presumably without a warrant. Similarly, they could also view my showers, but that would also violate the 4th amendment.

Comment: @McKay - The point is they don't care about your credit card numbers and chances are they wouldn't want to see you in the shower. American laws and liberties don't apply to everyone on SO, so when a question asks about privacy on the internet you can't always assume that they live with the same blanket of comfort you do.

Comment: You're looking at a game of cat and mouse no matter how many layers of encryption you implement, so you should be asking yourself "How secure does the information I'm transmitting have to be?". Without knowing the type of information you plan to transfer it would be hard to help you answer that question.

Comment: @Manish Rawat, could you clarify your question: are you asking about *your* private keys (or some user's private key) for an end-entity certificate (typically server or client certificate), or the private keys of the CAs that issue such certificates (which could thus be used for forging certificates that you would trust)?

Comment: @M.Babcock The point is that I know the sanctity of my private keys, because I generated them myself. If I want to transmit information across the Internet I can do so securely. The transmission will be secure.

Comment: @Bruno, Actually you stated all the typical scenario in which I consider my self hanging in. Y'day I go through an article: [link](http://zd.net/pJqSZQ) stating that, if the private keys of CA's being hacked  then MITM attacker can forge the fake certificate in between but that requires a lot privilage and that privilage I hope govt can only have, So govt agencies are always the GOD of all the hackers and can see your USERS credentials information with the ease. So still we are allowing the SSL to be driven by other CA's who can also hit by some BAD guys & if they got hit we also hit somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody except you could possibly share your private key with the government: it does not leave your computer when you get your SSL certificate from the certification authority.

Comment: but is there any law which allow the govt agencies to get our private keys from our servers.

Comment: @ManishRawat if you are under a criminal investigation, the government may take not only the keys from your server, but also the server itself. In all other cases, there is this pesky law called the Fourth Amendment to the United States Constitution that prohibits the government from taking anything that you own without you giving it to them. There was this stupid idea of GAK, which has been floating around in the early years of the internet, but it has been happily dead for good fifteen years now.

Answer (score 0):

Private keys are not shared with anyone. Public keys are. If I generate a key, I have a public key portion, and a private key. I share the public key with whoever I want (say SSL users, MIT key databases), and we can still communicate with that key, but no one else has the private key portion.

Comment: I wouldn't put my money on that, you can never be 100% sure

Comment: No, I know that that's the case, because I generated them myself. Example: I generate a set of keys using PGP say. Only do I have the public and private keys. Then I submit the key to the [MIT Key Server](http://pgp.mit.edu/) At that point, I have done all of the work needed. The only way around that is if PGP is backdoored to somehow get the key to the government.

Comment: @McKay, I think the question is about the private keys of well-established CAs (e.g. Verisign), in the context of PKI, not PGP/web of trust.

Comment: @McKay: yes absolutely the question also pointed to the CA's private keys which can be hacked by some other guys, or govt can ask them forcefully. NO idea whether the law states that or not, any comment would be highly ac-knowledgeable for me.